# Как передать в Task параметр

Tags: c#, tpl

Вопрос как передать в класс Task или Task функцию с параметром, интересуют все способы. Спасибо.

Comment: Опишите то, что вы хотите сделать и приложите код, где вы пытались это сделать. Либо гуглите.

Comment: Что означает «передать в класс `Task`»? Опишите, что вы делаете, и что хотите получить.

Comment: Нужно создать задачу Task, так что бы она принимала делегат который может принимать аргумент.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вероятно, вам нужно что-то вроде этого

```
private void RunAsync()
{
    string param = "Hi";
    Task.Run(() => MethodWithParameter(param));
}

private void MethodWithParameter(string param)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: А как при этом обойтись без замыкания на param?..